# sugar crm invalid package

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I am new to sugar crm and trying to install a theme from here [smack green sugar theme](https://www.smackcoders.com/store/free-sugar-theme-collection-2014-smack-green-theme.html). It is showing me the error `invalid package`.

before this the error was `ZIP Error(0): Status(0): Arhive(upload:` then I follow this [sugar crm installation guides](https://salesagility.com/index.php/forum/8-aos-5x/1872-aos-installation-issues-read-this-first). But now it is showing me the invalid package. Can't understand where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known Sugar crm problem. First you should check your permissions on the upload folder. The problem ist that the upload was not correct and you have now a incomplete package uploaded where some files are missing.

http://forums.sugarcrm.com/f3/zip-error-5-status-0-while-upgrade-6-2-2-a-74538/#post260045

Here is a good post how to fix that problem.

Comment: now the error is 
The zip file is missing a manifest.php file. Cannot proceed. but the file is present there

Comment: That link is now dead, as the forum changed the link schema.

Also, this is still an error in SuiteCRM, the successor to SugarCRM.

Answer (score 0):

Try uncompressing and then compressing the module, before upload. That works for this headache.

Answer (score 0):

A reason for this error could also be that you are archiving the Module including the containing folder. You should only archive the files inside the Module folder

Solution found here: [StudyHorror Blog](http://techs.studyhorror.com/sugarcrm-zip-error-status-archive-i-91)

Example using "zip" on linux:

```
zip ModuleName.zip manifest.php files
```